# Twitter friends/ids api

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to have this in Jquery:

```
function getfromuser(username)  {
var contenitore = [];
var appourl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=' + username;
$.getJSON(appourl, function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        if (item.ids !== undefined) {
            for (var i=0, elemento; elemento = item.ids[i++];) {
                contenitore[i]=item;
            };
        };
    });
});
getid(contenitore);
};
```

I need only to store the IDS in an array. But calling: https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=xxxxxx
I got the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=xxxxxx.
>   Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to request [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), otherwise this is [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You can do this by simply providing the callback param in the URL:

```
var appourl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&callback=?&screen_name=' + username;
```

Here a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPMNb/)

```
function getfromuser(username) {
    var contenitore = [];
    var appourl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&callback=?&screen_name=' + username;
    $.getJSON(appourl, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};

getfromuser('unclebobmartin');
```